# Cropping the image to aspect ratio in bootstrap responsive grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem:** I am trying to place images in the [responsive grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) of the Twitter's Bootstrap, so they will be scaled into the given space (for responsive CSS size of the column will differ for different devices). I want them to fit into the aspect ratio -- lets assume it is a square.

[Standard CSS cropping technique](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/) do not work if I want the images to be rescaled by Bootstrap to fit the grid design. Negative margins works only for cutting top and bottom part -- when the height of the image has to be cut, and the width is left unchanged (e.g. to put portrait image into the square).

I have found that [this technique](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio) for specifying aspect ratio to cut the width leaving the height unchanged (putting landscape image into the square) works well with Bootstrap's scaling.

[The example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/EZLA5/6/) of the cropped images for size 1600x400 and 400x1600. So far I checked it in current Chrome and Safari. **Edit:** Fixed to also work in Firefox.

**Question:** How can I do it in one way for both: cutting the width and the height. How to do arbitrary crop on an image, choosing the rectangle, to be properly rescaled by Bootstrap?
How can I crop to some aspect ratio without the prior knowledge of the size of the image?

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your solution only has to work in modern browsers and the img-tag isn't mandatory, using images as background has helped me out often in responsive designs. 
You can easily position backgrounds in the center and make them fit their container.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/wAqSV/2/

Comment: It look great and works, but it is designed for the case when I center the cropped image. I need to use is where I can choose how much to crop from both sides (e.g. the face of the person is on the top and I always need to show it). My idea lets to do that and I have no idea how to deal with background in CSS :( Your solution looks great, I don't need to know the aspect ration of the image, so it would be great if I could use that. Ideal would be if I could mark the point and require that it should be as close to the center as possible. but I guess it is the different question. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I think I am wishing to much. Moving cropped image from the center and  not knowing the aspect ratio? I am getting bit academic, I already have what I can use :) Thank you again!

Comment: :) You could use extra classes and position the background in % or top/bottom/left/right to move the image — but of course would be a manual job to set this correctly. 

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/wAqSV/4/